# Find cost of sql equality selection query with formula

Tags: sql, performance, time-complexity, formula

Does anyone know what the correct way/formula is to find the cost of an equality selection query in SQL for a heap file?

My textbook gives me:

```
0.5B(D+RC)
where:
B = data pages
R = records per page
D = average time to read/write a disk page 
C = average time to process a record
```

But I've come across several other resources that gives the cost as just : `0.5BD`

The only reason I'm questioning the textbook is that I don't have C (avg processing time). 
I'm asked to calculate how long this query will take (in I/O's and hours) :

```
select name from Emp where ssn=1000
```

I have the information for # of data pages (B), # of records per page (R), total access time (D), but not C

Alternatively, is there a completely different way of calculating this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct in their own sense. The textbook formula also considers the CPU cost along with the I/O cost.